# ObservableCollection And WPF ListBox Binding

Tags: wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I have ObservableCollection and WPF ListBox to bind each other.
I want to display Chip position at Listbox simultaneously  when ObservableCollection is added.

```
<Window x:Class="Apeiron.ZoneSetter.ZoneSetterWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        Height="765" Width="765">
         <Grid>                  
            <ListBox Name="lbPosList" ItemsSource="{Binding }" ></ListBox>
         </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Case 1) It works well. When ObservableCollection is changed, it shows chnaged chip pos at ListBox.

```
public partial class ZoneSetterWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public ZoneSetterWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbChipList.DataContext = SelectedZoneChipList;            
    }

    public void AddChip(ZoneMapChipInfo chip)
    {
          if (!m_SelectedChipDic.ContainsKey(chip.Point))
        {
            m_SelectedChipDic.Add(chip.ChipPos, chip);                
            m_selectedzonechiplist.Add(chip);
        }
    }


    private Dictionary<Point, ZoneMapChipInfo> m_SelectedChipDic = new Dictionary<Point, ZoneMapChipInfo>();

    private ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo> m_selectedzonechiplist = new ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo>();
    public ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo> SelectedZoneChipList
    {
        get
        {
            return m_selectedzonechiplist;
        }

    }       

  }
```

Case 2) It doesn't work. Although ObservableCollection is changed, it doesn't shows chnaged chip pos at ListBox.

```
public partial class ZoneSetterWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ZoneSetterWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbChipList.DataContext = SelectedZoneChipList;            
    }

    public void AddChip(ZoneMapChipInfo chip)
    {
          if (!m_SelectedChipDic.ContainsKey(chip.Point))
        {
            m_SelectedChipDic.Add(chip.ChipPos, chip);                
            m_selectedzonechiplist.Add(chip);
        }
    }


    private Dictionary<Point, ZoneMapChipInfo> m_SelectedChipDic = new Dictionary<Point, ZoneMapChipInfo>();

    private ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo> m_selectedzonechiplist = new ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo>();
    public ObservableCollection<ZoneMapChipInfo> SelectedZoneChipList
    {
        get
        {
             ObservableCollection<WaferZoneMapChipInfo> result = new ObservableCollection<WaferZoneMapChipInfo>();
            foreach (ZoneMapChipInfo info in m_SelectedChipDic.Values)
            {
                result.Add(info);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }       

}
```

I want to synchronize m_SelectedChipDic  and  SelectedZoneChipList always,
   and show ChipPosition of SelectedZoneChipList  at ListBox.

I don't know differernce of above two case.

Is there someone to understand me about above problem.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your first approach `SelectedZoneChipList` returns `m_selectedzonechiplist` to which the list view is then bound. This is why it is updating the UI when you add something to that list. In your second approach `SelectedZoneChipList` returns a completely new list unrelated to `m_selectedzonechiplist`. So when you add something to `m_selectedzonechiplist` nothing will happen because the `ListBox` is bound to a completely different object.

The binding to the `ListBox` works roughly like this:

1. The UI gets the `DataContext` once when it establishes the binding.
2. It subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` changed event handler (which `ObservableCollection` implements).
3. Every time the collection is changed it raises an event to which the UI reacts.

**Update**: In regards to `I want to synchronize m_SelectedChipDic and SelectedZoneChipList always`: You could get rid of the `ObservableCollection` and make your `m_SelectedChipDic` an [ObservableDictionary](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/) and bind your `ListView` to that one instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your answer helps that I understand ObservableCollection. I'll try it. ObservableDictionary!! By the way, Which item of ObservableDictionary is bound? Key or Value?